# Couchbase - Unable to connect to http://localhost:8091/index.html after install

Tags: couchbase

I've just installed CouchBase Server Community Edition v2.1.1 on a Windows Server 2003 32bit machine. The installation process went smoothly, but when it fires the browser to load the Web Admin Console at  `http://localhost:8091/index.html` the browser issues a Unable to Connect web page. Here are the relevant data:

- the service "Couchbase" has been created and **is properly running**.
- the netstat -a -b -p tcp shows that there are **no listening entries for :8091**.

I've used previous versions of CouchBase (2.0.0) and Membase (1.7.1) in the past, so I'm already aware of the dreadful *IP address acquisition issue* as stated in other ServerFault and StackOverflow entries and also solved them in the past: the problem with v2.1.1 is that it lacks the appropriate entries (NS_NAME, %IP_ADDR% etc.) in service_register.bat and/or in config.dat to manually solve the issue as suggested in other topics.

I also tried uninstall/reinstall, disabled some NIC to see if I could overcome the IP issue, and even install on a different machine in the same network (another win2k3 server 32bit) without any luck.

Anyone having this issue and/or solved it?

Comment: Having looked around to try and solve the same problem myself for a client (64-bit Windows 2008, but same symptoms) the closest thing I've got to an answer is the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22038572/333519 Have you tried/did you try (I'm well aware this post is nearly two years old) installing to a directory without spaces in the names?